Reentry after visa
I’m a Tier 2 visa holder and planning to resign my job. The last working day is on July 28th. Can I visit my sister's home in Ireland and come back to the UK? I will be leaving the UK by August 14th.
Update: Thanks for your responses. Is there any immigration check while coming back to the UK from Ireland? I’m planning to go for only a 5 day trip. I have a visitor's visa for Ireland, but I need to return back to the UK after that visit.

Your employer has 10 days from your final work date to inform the Home Office that your employment has ended. Shortly after your employer has informed the Home Office, you will receive a curtailment of leave advice from the Home Office stating you must leave the country within 60 days or by the end date on your visa (whichever is earlier).
I think one issue for you could be timing, especially if your employer informs the Home Office promptly and the Home Office sends you the curtailment letter immediately. Your trip to Ireland could then mean that you would be deemed to have left the UK (although much sooner than the allowed 60 day maximum), and hence would not be eligible to return using your current visa.
There are usually no immigration controls if you enter the UK from the Common Travel Area, and none on the land border between Ireland and Northern Ireland. You need to get permission to enter the UK when arriving from Ireland if you’re a visa national who doesn’t have a valid UK visa.
